# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: year

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Using SQLite3 and got this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: year

SQLite3 newbie over here. 
Really confused right now as to what part of the code went wrong...

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



def search(title="",author="",year="",isbn=""):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?",(title,author,year,isbn))
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

connect()
print(search(year=1918))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: One thought: maybe there is no such column because you already created the table, in an earlier version of your code which didn't have that column, so the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` silently returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have that column.

To list all the columns of the table `book`:

```
sqlite3 books.db
```

and after that:

```
.schema book
```

If you don't have a column with the name `year` you can add it by altering the table, or you can delete your old table and create it again.

Comment: Haha, right. I didn't have the column cause the first time I ran it cause there was this typo in "author". Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that no such column exists (the message is correct) because you already created the table, in an earlier version of your code which didn't have that column, so the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` silently returns.

You could very this manually by examining `.schema` in interactive `sqlite3`.

And/or you could cover the possibility in your code by checking the table structure with e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;
```

If it's not correct, you could use `ALTER TABLE book ADD COLUMN ...` - if you wanted to rename a column, it's more complicated: [SQLite Query Language: ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: Ahh!!! That's exactly what happened. Got a typo earlier, so I didn't have the column in an earlier version. Thank you!!